# .submit function not running when invalid with kendo validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a form that's validated via kendo validator, and I need some things to happen when the form is invalid besides the usual marking of invalid fields. Unfortunately something seems to prevent a function bound via the submit method from ever firing unless the entire form is valid.

For example, this behavior seems to occur in one of Telerik's own demos:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/index

it contains the code:

```
var validator = $("#ticketsForm").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator"),
status = $(".status");

$("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (validator.validate()) {
        status.text("Hooray! Your tickets has been booked!")
            .removeClass("invalid")
            .addClass("valid");
    } else {
        status.text("Oops! There is invalid data in the form.")
            .removeClass("valid")
            .addClass("invalid");
    }
});
```

The if block runs when everything is filled in and valid on the form, but the else block never fires. In fact inserting some alerts() shows that the entire function doesn't run unless the entire form is valid. This appears to function in contrast to the jQuery documentation for the submit method (https://api.jquery.com/submit/), where a functionally similar function runs on any attempt to submit. The only thing I can guess is that something about kendo validator prevents this from happening, but I can't seem to figure out an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like kendo automatically validates form when button clicked and when validation fails, kendo stops event propagation and jquery submit is not firing.

You can replace button with anchor:

```
<a id="buttonSubmit" class="k-button k-primary">Submit</a>
```

and then bind click event to validate it manually:

```
$("#buttonSubmit").click(function(event) {...
```

and rename `status` variable, because it is reserved word:

```
status2 = $(".status");
```

Comment: That seemed to do it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how to properly establish "rules"

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/validator/overview#error-messages

Comment: I'm not really sure how that's going to help. I don't have a problem with how elements are being marked invalid, the problem is the function bound to submit isn't running when it should.